# Don't understand fully how "なきゃよかった" means if ___ hadn't or if I hadn't ___

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances, usage, conditionals

Is the なきゃ like referring to there not being something presently or something? Or is it more like [the hypothetical idea of not doing something][was good]...though even if it was that I don't think I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given us much to work with, but we can at least dig into what we have.  :)

### The sample text

- なきゃよかった

This breaks down to four basic meaning components.

#### なきゃ

This is a contraction from なければ.  The basic progression:

- *nakereba*
- *nakerya*
- *nakya*

#### よかった

This is the past tense of よい, which is also basically the same thing as いい.  (Modern *ii* is a sound shift from older-and-still-used *yoi*.)

The past tense of modern *-i* adjectives is in turn a contraction of the basic adverbial ～く form + あった, the past tense of old copula ("to be" verb) あり that turned into modern ある・あります.

So the core to understanding this なきゃよかった is understanding the implications of the ～ばいい construction.

### The meaning of ～ばいい: the general case

The ～ばいい construction literally breaks down more or less like so:

- ～ば: only if (what ever comes before), then...
- いい: it's good

Put it together, and this means *"it's only good if `[VERB / ADJ]`"*.  Idiomatically, this is used similarly to English "should".

Examples:

- あの本を読【よ】めばいい → "it's only good if [I, you, they, etc.] read that book" → "[I, you, they, etc.] should read that book"
- 気温【きおん】が高【たか】ければいい → "it's only good if the temperature is high" → "it should be warm" (as in, it needs to be warm for some specific purpose, like for plants or for an activity)

### The meaning of ～なきゃよかった: the specific case

So なきゃよかった → なければよかった → "it [was / would only have been] good if not `[VERB / ADJ]`" → "it shouldn't have been `[VERB / ADJ]`".

Depending on what comes after, this might have different nuances.  For instance, adding a ～のに on the end brings in a sense of regret: *"oh, **if only** it hadn't have been X..."*

Examples:

- 値段【ねだん】が高【たか】くなければよかったのに → *"if only the price had not been (as / so) high"* → implying that they wanted to buy it, but didn't because they considered the price to be too high
- 眠【ねむ】くなければよかったのに → *"if only I hadn't have been (so) sleepy"* → implying that they wound up missing out on something

---

Please comment if the above does not fully address your question.

Comment: 値段が安ければよかったのに doesn't have ない in it. Did you mean to say 高くなければ?

Comment: Did you mean やすければ for 安ければ ?

Comment: @aguijonazo -- ha!  Clearly I was getting tired as the day went along.  I'll fix that.  :)

Comment: @dvx2718, yes indeed.  But actually as aguijonazo points out, I should have used a different construction anyway.  I'll fix it momentarily.  :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I understand it more fully now. Knowing that the potential/conditional specifically means/implies "*only* if ___" helps, I think.